# Java 8 optional .map().orElse always returns orElse

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I'm trying to get the version from a package and am having trouble implementing it. 
This code returns the correct package:

```
private String getVersion(){
    Optional<Class<?>> optional = Arrays.stream(getClass().getInterfaces())
            .filter(cl -> isCorrectClass(cl))
            .findFirst();
    return optional.isPresent() ? optional.get().getPackage().getImplementationVersion() : "";
}
```

But I think it would be neater to do

```
private String getVersionWithMap() {
    return Arrays.stream(getClass().getInterfaces())
            .filter(cl -> isCorrectClass(cl))
            .findFirst()
            .map(cl -> cl.getPackage().getImplementationVersion())
            .orElse("");
}
```

However, getVersionWithMap() always returns the empty string "".

---

**EDIT:**
SOLVED. It ended up being the frontend that was wrong. Found this after going back to using getVersion() and having the same issue of no visible version in the frontend.

Comment: Does your first code with `... ? ... : ...` work?

Comment: @Sweeper yeah, the first function works

Comment: Does `cl.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` actually return something? Your code with the ternary operator is slightly different compared to what you do in the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both functions work, the issue was somewhere else and I didn't test that part, assuming the fix would be here. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

If `cl.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` returns a `null` value your  second code will invoke `orElse()` because the result of `map()` is an empty `Optional`.

In the first code that's not the case, you will return `null` directly from the method. You are comparing two different codes.

Comment: You are assuming that `cl.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` may return `null`. I'm not sure that's the case here. Anyway, the question led me to believe that the OP's first snippet returns a non-empty String while the second returns an empty String. It doesn't make sense that the OP's statement "returns the correct package" means returns null.

Comment: @Eran is correct, I expect it to return a string. Both functions ended up working, it was frontend that was retrieving wrong x.x

Comment: Although this did teach me that if .map returns null, the .orElse case is used. Thanks for that!